# I am trying to add an ImageRow using Eureka, why do I keep getting use of unresolved identifier ImageRow Error, what am I not doing correctly?

Tags: swift3, uiimage, eureka-forms

```
import UIKit
import Eureka
import DigitsKit
//MARK: HiddenRowsExample
class SettingsViewController: FormViewController {

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                let section = Section()
           //line below gives me an error: Use of unresolved Identifier 'ImageRow'     
                    <<< ImageRow() {  
                        $0.title = "Profile Photo"
                        $0.sourceTypes = [.PhotoLibrary, .SavedPhotosAlbum]
                        $0.clearAction = .yes(style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive)

                        }.cellUpdate({(cell, row) -> () in
                            row.accessoryView?.layer.cornerRadius = 18
                            row.accessoryView?.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:34, height:34)
                })

                section.append(TextRow() { $0.placeholder = "Username" })
                section.append(PasswordRow() { $0.placeholder = "Password" })
                section.append(EmailRow(){$0.placeholder = "Email"})
                section.append(PhoneRow() {$0.placeholder = "Phone"})
                section.append(
                    ButtonRow() { (row:ButtonRow) ->Void in
                        row.title = "Save"
                        row.onCellSelection(self.save)
                        row.cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0/255, green: 87.0/255, blue: 184.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
                        row.cell.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score 4):

ImageRow has been removed from Eureka in the latest version.

Follow the link:
https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/759

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14787417)

Comment: @AbdulRasheed I disagree, the essential point is that ImageRow was removed, which is included here.

Answer (score 0):

Add ImageRow to your podfile   `pod 'ImageRow', '~> 3.0'`
 and do an import `import ImageRow`